# Android - Can't open asset file

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an sqlite file in the assets folder. I'm using a database manager class that has been referenced thousands of times in other stack overflow posts: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

```
private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open( DB_NAME );
```

The problem is the open() method (or getAssets?) that keeps throwing an IOException. My path and file names:

```
private static final String DB_NAME = "attractioninfo";
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/seattle.tourists/";
```

Another related question I have is about the path. I've checked the files on my testing phone (samsung galaxy sII) but I don't see a /data/data/mypackagename/... anywhere. Where exactly is this in internal storage? I am using Android 2.2.

EDIT: I did more testing and I've also found that on first install (this means that there is no database file on the phones internal storage yet, it needs to be copied there) this line doesn't work either (I get an SQLiteException)

```
private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY );
```

FULL CODE:

```
package seattle.tourists;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "attractioninfo";
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/seattle.tourists/databases/";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "ExtraInfo";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context application context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper( Context context ) {
        super( context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION );
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates empty database on system and rewrites it with existing database
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if ( dbExist ) {
            // do nothing, the database already exists;
        }
        else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDatabase();
            }
            catch ( IOException e ) {
                throw new Error( "Error copying database" );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if a database exists
     * @return true if database exists, false otherwise;
     */
    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY );
        }
        catch ( SQLiteException e ) {
            int x = 5;
        }

        if ( checkDB != null )
            checkDB.close();

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copes database from assets-folder to system folder, where it can be
     * accessed and handled. This is done by transferring byte-stream.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
        InputStream myInput = assets.open( DB_NAME );

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream( outFileName );

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte [] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
        int length;
        while ( ( length = myInput.read( buffer ) ) > 0 )
            myOutput.write( buffer, 0, length );

        // close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        return db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY );
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if ( db != null )
            db.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I was using the wrong file format. I was using an txt/SQL format and not sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

in your path:

private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/seattle.tourists/";

---

there is a missing directory wc is the "/database/" after package name.

Answer (score -1):

to open a db from Assets use

```
AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("DB Name");
```

`Another related question I have is about the path. I've checked the files on my testing phone (samsung galaxy sII) but I don't see a /data/data/mypackagename/..`

You can not see your DB on your device due to security. If you actually want to see your DB. Then you need to install your App on Emulator

EDIT:

Code to copy the database

```
 private static String db_path = "/data/data/your.package.name/databases/";
 private static final String database_name = "search";

 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    String outFileName = db_path + database_name+".db";
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int i, r;
    AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
    String fn = String.format(database_name);
        InputStream is = am.open(fn);
    while ((r = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
       myOutput.write(buffer, 0, r);
        is.close();

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();

}
```

to check DB

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = db_path + database_name+".db";

        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

MAKE sure you have added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

in you `manifest file`.

Comment: That is exactly the same thing I have in my code except I omit the AssetManager. Tried the AssetManager and it does not work.

Comment: Naeem, I appreciate your help. Tried your changes, but it doesn't work. I get the same errors. "unable to load database file" and the same exceptions.

Comment: Am I writing to external storage? I thought I was writing to internal storage on the phone?